# Expressjs - squirrelly - How do we include a template inside another template

Tags: node.js, express

I have been using the squirrelly template of `express.js`. I have tried many ways but was unsuccessful in doing so. I am trying to include another template file inside the first template

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the world of example</h1>

    {{include("footer")/}}
</body>
</html>
```

and footer.squirrely has

```
copyright example {{counter}}
```

and my route has

```
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.render('index', {
        counter: 1
    });
});
```

Can the readers please guide me as to what needs to be done to have this working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the way to do this. Basically use `renderFile` method

```
var compiledTemplate2 = Sqrl.renderFile('./views/footer.squirrelly', {
    fav: "Squirrelly2!"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I LOVE Squirrelly! This was really tricky for me, but I finally figured it out too! :)

I put the code inside of express middleware, so that it would be loaded on every page.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){
    let template_header = sqrl.renderFile('./views/header.squirrelly',
         { user:req.session.USER_DATA, // this is from npm module 'express-session'
           domain:domain, // Useful for localhost vs live
           page:req.originalUrl // Useful for menus and "active" tabs.
         })
        /* Here, we define "header" as the HTML we just compiled above */
        .then(compiled => { sqrl.templates.define("header", sqrl.compile(compiled)); return true; })
        /* Then we allow the middleware to pass :) */
        .then(compiled => { next() })
});
```

Then inside of my dashboard.squirrelly file, I can insert it anywhere like so:

```
{{@include("header")/}}
```

Version 8 of Squirrelly requires the "@" symbol, compared to other answers here.

Then finally, I'd render it like normal in my app.js:

```
/* Middleware filled in the partial already! :) */
app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res){
    res.render('dashboard', {
        domain:domain,
        user:req.session.USER_DATA
});
```

I'm not an expert, and I'm sure someone much smarter than me would have a better approach to this.

Technically, you could also wrap it in an async function for multiple partials as well.

Hopefully someone out there who is needing this can also find it too :)